# Error reporting in TFS with Cake build and MSBuild

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild, cakebuild

On compilation errors in one of my projects, the build results page on TFS is significantly less informative than I'd hoped; I only get this:

[image: build-errors-no-info]

I had hoped more for something like this (from a different project built the same way):

[image: build-errors-with-info]

**What do I need to do to get TFS to show the specific errors?**

---

I build both projects using [Cake build](https://cakebuild.net/) with the following target definition:

```cs
Task("Build")
    .IsDependentOn("Update version")
    .Does(() =>
    {
        Information("Verbosity: {0}", verbosity);
        MSBuild(solutionPath, settings =>
        {
            settings.SetConfiguration(configuration);
            settings.SetVerbosity(verbosity);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like it could be solved by using a custom [MSBuild logger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171471). Currently we do not have one built into Cake, but if you add an issue to [Cake's issue tracker](https://github.com/cake-build/cake/issues) we can take this into consideration for a future release.

As a temporary solution, you could write a custom logger and provide it to the [MSBuild alias](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.common.tools.msbuild/2dee1d75/486a3884) using the [ArgumentCustomization property](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.core.tooling/d75cd243/60ae911b) on the MSBuild tool settings.

If TFS provides a MSBuild logger out of the box, you should be able to reference that one.

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed possible, albeit perhaps a little less straightforward than I'd hoped. Issue filed for a nicer interface to this functionality: https://github.com/cake-build/cake/issues/702